# Convert complete result set into String within SQL (HSQLDB)

Tags: java, sql, string, hsqldb

As part of a Secure Code course I am given a vulnerable Java system, where queries are built up using string concatintion, and so on. Following is the respective code line that I have to SQL inject to retrieve log-in data:

```
String comment;
int articleID;
//...
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO comment (text, article_id) VALUES ('" + comment + "', " + articleId + ")");
```

`comment` can be set to any text, it is just read plain-text from a textbox. Therefore, I thought about setting the textbox text to an `SELECT` statement, reading the complete login data (table `user` has columns `login` and `password`):

```
' || (SELECT login || password FROM user) || '
```

which in overall should result in the query

```
INSERT INTO comment (text, article_id) VALUES ('' || (SELECT login || password FROM user) || '', 4)
```

yet, this results in

> org.hsqldb.HsqlException: cardinality violation

**Question:**

I assume this is because `(SELECT login || password FROM user)` is not a single string, but a result set, and may therefore not be concatenated using `||`.

Is it possible to convert the complete result set to one string in a way it can be used in this SQL injection scenario (in standard SQL / SQL that works on HSQLDB)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, as there is obviously more than one user and multiple rows are returned from the SELECT.

You can add `LIMIT 1` to the SELECT to get the first row. You can also create a string array from the inner SELECT. See the guide.

In HSQLDB each database user has separate access rights to the tables. In a real deployment the user that inserts comments will not even see the existence of the table that contains the password, let alone select from it.